# Git Help: how to reset git? Not branches, but all of git?

Tags: git, git-bash

I was having problems with git, so i tried unsucessfully to uninstall and try again, but now it wont take any commands, and if i try to go to desktop it says:

```
MyName@DESKTOP-IQ094LF MINGW64 /
$ ls
bin/  etc/           LICENSE.txt  proc/              unins000.dat   usr/
cmd/  git-bash.exe*  magic.py     ReleaseNotes.html  unins000.exe*
dev/  git-cmd.exe*   mingw64/     tmp/               unins000.msg

MyNAme@DESKTOP-IQ094LF MINGW64 /
$ cd ~/Desktop
bash: cd: /c/Users/Myname/Desktop/myDocuments/Desktop: No such file or directory

MyName@DESKTOP-IQ094LF MINGW64 /
```

I dont know why its going to my docmuments and i dont know why uninstalling and reinstalling wont help. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: It sounds like you have an incorrect home path, since `cd ~/Desktop` mentions `Desktop` twice in the wrong path.

Comment: Yes, not sure it's related to git. Try `echo $HOME` and see what you get, maybe reinstalling git changed the home path in some way.

Comment: To add a bit to what colinD said: bash isn't part of Git, it is just *supplied with* the version of Git you're using. I'm not sure where and how the Windows port(s) of bash set $HOME but look at your .bashrc and .profile (in your actual home directory, not the one that `~` is mis-expanding to) and see if you've overridden the `HOME=` setting.